# Why Resnet18 works better than VGG16 architecture?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, computer-vision

Based on https://towardsdatascience.com/vggnet-vs-resnet-924e9573ca5c and
my understanding, Resnet18 architecture is faster because it is based on skip connections which not allow vanishing gradient problem to occur.
My question is, VGG16 uses Relu activation functions at each layer than how vanishing gradient problem occurs in it?

Please correct me if I'm wrong. Suggestions are welcomed!!

Comment: *No* machine learning architectures in general "works better" for all classes of problems than other https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem

Comment: Better how? Being faster and being "better" aren't generally synonymous, especially for neural networks. Are you asking something about vanishing gradient? Or about relu activations? How are you comparing VGG16 and Resnet? Please [edit] to be specific about what you know and what you would like to know.

Answer (score 0):

They both use ReLu and without skip connections which allow gradients to backpropagate around blocks, gradient vanishing is inevitable with increasing network depth. ReLu doesn't really "solve" gradient vanishing, there's just a lesser chance of it happening compared to a sigmoid activation function for example.